# How to override an ng-disable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i the following is one of my comment box with angularjs

```
<tr>

<td colspan="5"><br/>Comments*<div><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="60" ng-model="final_data.drc_scope" placeholder="Add comments here"
 ng-disabled="is_team==0 || isDisableComments || final_data.status=='confirmed'" ng-change="changeValue()"></textarea></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

It will disable the button when the status is confirmed and when the right person logged in.

Now I need to add a new button, whenver the user click on it it will override the existing ng-disable condition and enable the button. I already have scope their 'isDisableComments' when click the edit button/new button it will return value 0. But its not working. Any idea guys?

Comment: can you share ur js code

Comment: `$scope.secondPoEdit = 1;
    $scope.secondPo_editSetting = function(){
        $scope.isDisableComments = 0; //Enable first comment
    }`

Comment: i dont see change value defined

Answer (score 0):

You should use AND operator like this:

```
ng-disabled="(is_team==0 || final_data.status=='confirmed') && isDisableComments"
```

If is team and is confirmed, and isDisableComments is true, the button is disabled.
But if is false, not matter the value of the first expression, it will be enabled.

Comment: Its not working Leonardo. The comment button is now even enabled by default

Comment: Tried,  `<tr>
                                    <td colspan="5"><br/>
                                        Comments*<div><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="60" ng-model="final_data.drc_scope"
                                                                    placeholder="Add comments here"
                                                                    ng-disabled="(is_team==0 || final_data.status =='confirmed') && isDisableComments"
                                                                    ng-change="changeValue()"></textarea></div>
</td>
 </tr>`

Comment: It should start as true, so if the first expression is true will be disabled, and then to false so the entire expression is false and is not disabled anymore.